# Is there any keyboard shortcut to switch between scopes in IntelliJ's Find in Files?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to switch between "In Project", "Module", "Directory", and "Scope" without using a mouse?

[image: Switch Scopes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select the Scope mode, the scopes drop-down gets focus and you can change it using up/down arrows. If Scope is already selected, you can use Alt+D, Alt+S to switch to Directory mode and back to Scope mode to focus the drop-down. Or you can press Tab several times until the drop-down gains the focus and then use up/down arrows to change the scope.

Comment: Sorry, I may have not been clear. My question should have been worded, is there a way to switch between "In Project", "Module", "Directory", "Scope" with out using a mouse?

Comment: Yes, with mnemonics, see the underlined letters, use Alt+P, Alt+M, Alt+D, Alt+S.